# ruby on rails before_save increments different column of table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, sql-update

here is my **like.rb model**

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :post_id

  before_save :increment_post_total_likes

  before_destroy :decrement_post_total_likes

  scope :desc_ordered, :order => "created_at DESC"

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  def increment_post_total_likes
    p = Post.find(self.post_id)
    p.increment!(:total_likes)
    p.save
  end

  def decrement_post_total_likes
    p = Post.find(self.post_id)
    p.decrement!(:total_likes)
    p.save
  end

  def self.alreadyLiked(post_id, user_id)
    where(:user_id => user_id, :post_id => post_id).any?
  end

  def self.already_liked?(user_id)
    exists?(:user_id => user_id)
  end

end
```

the problem is that when i like a post, it increments the post `total_likes` column but also increments the another table column which those 2 share associated columns like `post_id` and `user_id` and i don't get why...

I want to use before_save and before_destroy only on the **likes** table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`increment!` will [save the record for you](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!). Try it without the bang.